# Assembly Language x86 JL instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having troubles getting the correct answer. I understand that JL instruction is to jump if the left operand < right operand. How do I know which is my right or left?  When I worked it out by hand, I chose 1111 1110b as my right operand. So, I received 00FC as the result in hex. In the program, I received 00FB, can anyone help me figure out my mistake? Thank you!

```
MOV AL, 1111 1110b
CMP AL, 1111 0110b
JL DEST 
DEC AL
DEST: DEC AL
DEC AL
```

Comment: Oddly enough it depends on assembler syntax. But with the Intel syntax you have @Jester is correct.  It's AL < 0xF6.  What may be confusing you is that `JL` is a _signed_ check, and both 0xFE and 0xF6 are negative.

Answer (score 1):

In `CMP AL, 1111 0110b` clearly `AL` is the left operand, and that holds `1111 1110b` (this is of course a slight oversimplification, but this is how the `Jcc` mnemonics have been chosen). Thus, the condition is `1111 1110b < 1111 0110b` but the comparison is signed, so that's interpreted as `-2 < -10` which is not true hence the jump is not taken meaning `AL` will be decremented by `3` giving `0xFB` (`-5`).

Comment: thank you, I understand what you are saying now! Can i get a clarification?  So, even though the jump is false, we will still DEC the DEST?  I thought if it was false, we only have to decrement once and ignore the DEST

Comment: Execution will of course continue into `dest`, there is no other jump to skip it. So all three of the `DEC` instructions will be performed. If the jump is not taken, the cpu executes instructions one by one as usual.